# Look up data based on multiple variables in VBA UserForm

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have created an UserForm in vba as follow:
[image]

Once a user fills out the form, the record will be saved on "Sheet2". For each Control ID, there should be 3 possible Activities. What I want to do is that after users type in the Control ID and Activity name, the form will be filled with existing data from "Sheet2". Here is what I have come up with by using "Index"/"Match" but it returns with "Type Mismatch" error.

```
Private Sub Reg3_AfterUpdate()

With Me
.Reg2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet2.Columns(3), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, (Sheet2.Columns(2) = CLng(Me.Reg1)) * (Sheet2.Columns(4) = CLng(Me.Reg3)), 0))

End With

End Sub
```

Reg1 is Control ID located in Column 2;
Reg2 is Full Name located in Column 3; and
Reg3 is Activity located in Column 4.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Thomas has a good solution. If you want to use only VBA (no Excel functions), you can also set a search loop like this:

```
With ws
    For row = fisrtRow To lastRow
        val = .Cells(row, col)
        If val = controlID And val = activity Then
            '....
        Else
            '...
        End If
    Next row
End With
```

Comment: Actual I didn't account for the second condition.  You solution is correct. +1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could get you on track

```
                            '-- lets assume you want value from row 1, column 3
                            '   from "Sheet2"
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim row As Integer, column As Integer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
row = 1
col = 3

Me.Reg2.Text = ws.Cells(row, col)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, the assumption that you are making is too rigid. I only know the columns that each variables in but I don't know the rows. That's why I used "Index/Match". I need to look up values based on two conditions (Control ID and Activity)

Answer (score 0):

```
here is the best solution for you


write the following code ih the after update event

Private Sub Reg3_AfterUpdate()
SheetS("SHEET2").Range("A1:C4").Select
 Selection.AutoFilter
    SheetS("SHEET2").Range("$A$1:$C$4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Product no",  Operator:=xlAnd

    SheetS("SHEET2")..Range("$A$1:$C$4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Activity",  Operator:=xlAnd

'add your code to get the value from range(a2:c2) like the following
FULLNAME.TEXT=SHEETS("sheet2").range("B2)
End Sub



'in this example I assume that the data is stored in range(A1:C4) 
'SO AFTER YOU APPLY THE FILTER YOU WILL GET ONE UNIQUE ROW  REPRESENTING 
'YOUR 'DATA  .THEN YOU JUST NEED TO IMPORT THE DATA FROM THE sheet2 CELLs

'and so on
```